# Is there any way to connect GKSession only through Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, gksession

Can we force `GKSession` connection only through Bluetooth?..I know its is possible through `GKPeerPickerController` , but i am not interested in `GKPeerPickerController` interface..I need to connect my application in two device only in Bluetooth rechability zone..but what happened is if WiFi is enabled , the device will still keep connection beyond the limit of Bluetooth.and for some other reasons i cant switch off my WiFi in device..any idea about this will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper way for forcing `GKSession` to connect only through Bluetooth.the only way i found is keep  server/client device WiFi off.So that it will connect via Bluetooth.Thank you,

Comment: Does this mean that it connects through WiFi always, unless WiFi isn't available, then falls back to bluetooth?

i.e.: Wifi has priority over Bluetooth?

Comment: Ya they giving first priority for wifi connection ,if it fails then it check with bluetooth connection